# Simple CSS Scale-Nine Layout

Tags: css, html

After all these years, I still haven't learned CSS layout, so bear with me. I'm trying to create a container with rounded corners that I generated in Photoshop. The background of the container is white, so I have eight images: top-left-corner, top, top-right-corner, right, bottom-right-corner, bottom, bottom-left-corner, and left.

The edges have a drop shadow around them so yes, I do need 8 sides. How would I lay this out in CSS? I tried and failed miserably to do it with a table + CSS. How would I do it using divs?

**EDIT:**
Simply speaking, how would I lay something out like the pseudo code below

```
[IMG][IMG WIDTH="100%"][IMG]
```

If I write this in HTML, my images are split over three lines. How do I get it all to fit on one line?

Comment: Do they need to be rounded for all browsers? This is possible in CSS3 without images. Check out this [CSS3 Generator](http://css3generator.com/). I've totally given up on rounded corners using images. Progressive enhancement for the win...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: [Curvy Corners](http://www.curvycorners.net/), it's a jQuery plugin that will look at your CSS and find any CSS3 properties for webkit: `-webkit-border-radius: 10px;` and make any corners with that CSS property round, in every browser.

I use it for IE and it works great! All you have to do is add the .js file to your directory and link it at the bottom of your HTML and it does all the work for you :)

Comment: You're right. CSS sucks right now, evidently JS is the only way to make this happen :-|

Answer (score 1):

I like the tutorials that have been put together by Matthew James Taylor.  These tutorials won't help much with rounded corners, but they are great for CSS layout ideas.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths

Comment: Very nice tutorials, I'll have to check them out :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, http://www.devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/.

Comment: All of those solutions are trying to do rounded corners using 5 images or less, ie: not a fluid solution. Is there another place that you know of that will let me, in CSS alone, layout these items?

Comment: Dan Cederholm (www.simplebits.com) has a good approach - http://simplebits.com/publications/bulletproof/code/ see code sample for first edition, chapter 5.